# How to prove the decomposition of implication?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have to prove the following statement : (A -> B) <-> ~A \/ B which is the decomposition of implication. I can use the ~~A -> A axiom as it is given in the exercise, but I'm stuck pretty early in the demonstration.

I start by splitting then introducing, then I've tried a bit of everything (right, left, apply the absurd axiom then introducing) but nothing looks convincing and I don't really know where to go from there...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is exactly the axiom you are given and thing you have to prove? Do they both start with a quantification `forall A`? If the `A` is a variable that is the same in both statements you give, then your statement is not provable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the axiom `forall A, ~~A -> A` that you were given, you can prove the law of the excluded middle, `forall A, A \/ ~A`.  They are actually logically equivalent.
If you do that, then it is easy for you to solve your assignment.

I don't give the full solution here because it is not good to give solutions to course exercises, and I promise you will learn from doing it.

But as a small hint, when trying to prove

```
Goal (forall A, ~ ~ A -> A) -> (forall A, A \/ ~ A).
```

the first steps are `intros H A. apply H. intros C.`